# Magento & vertnav extension

Tags: php, magento, error-reporting

I'm working on a magento project (v1.3.2.3) and i've installed the vertnav extension.

Contents vertnav.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="vertnav/navigation" name="catalog.vertnav" template="vertnav/left.phtml" before="-" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

This should show the vertnav on every page (correct me if im wrong)

Something weird is happening when changing error reporting from `"E_ALL | E_STRICT"` to `"E_ALL | ~E_STRICT"` in index.php

When set to `E_ALL | E_STRICT` the vertnav is NOT showed in the left bar.

When set to `E_ALL | ~E_STRICT` vertnav becomes visible.

I think this is really weird behaviour, hoping someone knows more about it.

Other blocks behave like normal.

Another issue we run into, and proberly related to this. We get a strict warning (only variables can be passed by reference; something like that) when accessing the admin directory (only on the live server), this is why we're considering to set error_reporting to `~E_STRICT`.

Offcourse our goal is to leave error_reporting set to `E_ALL | E_STRICT` but vertnav should be visible and admin accessible.

Going crazy :-)

// Roland

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this could be related to this at all.

But just one quick hint: if you want to set error reporting to E_ALL but not E_STRICT use:

```
E_ALL & ~E_STRICT
```

instead of:

```
E_ALL | ~E_STRICT
```

It might not make any difference, but that's the proper way to work with bitmasks(for more informations see [this](http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html)).

Also have you checked the contents of the Magento log file?

Path: `install_dir/var/log/system.log`